# Detecting the location (latitude and longitude) of utility poles in an area using Resnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, resnet

My objective is to find the location (latitude and longitude) of utility poles in an area using Resnet. My goal is similar to implementing this paper: https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/8/2484/pdf. I need help in implementing this paper in code using Python and Deep Learning.

Another helpful resource for getting photos from Google Street View: https://github.com/robolyst/streetview

Our code will be able to download photos from Google Street View for a specific area and, then, scan the photos to find any utility pole. The output will be the coordinates of all the poles in that area. The input to our model can be in the form of coordinates of the area or the Google Map url of the area.

I tried finding on the internet, but, there are very limited resources available on this topic. Any help will be appreciated.